# How can I make webpack dev server append a trailing slash?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would like webpack dev server to append a trailing slash to all resource requests that don't already have one.

For example:
My index lives at `/my/project/root/index.html`
I can access it through webpack dev server at
1. `/my/project/root` and
2. `/my/project/root/` (note the trailing slash here)

I would like requests to 1 to be redirected to 2.

I have experimented with the historyAPIFallback option, but the rewrites that you can provide to that option only pass through the request, they do not change the url.

Is it possible to redirect requests using webpack dev server?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I'm facing the same question.

Comment: @DILP, unfortunately not. In the end I worked around it by putting some extra code in my project build that would add a redirect to the initial request if the trailing slash was not present. I wrapped that in a condition and used the webpackDefinePlugin and tree shaking to remove it from production builds.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage webpack's [devServer.historyApiFallback](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) and [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback#rewrites) to append a trailing slash.

webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [{ from: /^.*[^/]$/, to: (context) => `${context.parsedUrl.pathname}/` }],
    },
  },
};
```

where

```js
rewrites: [{ from: /^.*[^/]$/, to: (context) => `${context.parsedUrl.pathname}/` }]
```

indicates append a trailing slash to any urls that does not have one.

Plus, a context object that has the following properties:

```
parsedUrl: Information about the URL as provided by the URL module's url.parse.
match: An Array of matched results as provided by String.match(...).
request: The HTTP request object.
```

**NOTE:** The answer above might throw `CANNOT GET <URL>` error on the web page if your `webpack.output.publicPath` is `auto` or `/`. In this case, simply do:

```js
rewrites: [{ from: /^.*[^/]$/, to: '/' }]
```